# MySQL5.1 Two queries I can't get working

Tags: mysql

First query I need help with - I have a table named Stadium which holds info about different Stadiums. More than one game can be played at a certain Stadium per day. Stadium.Number refers to the number of the Stadium, Stadium.Date refers to the date of the game. I need to make a query which lists for each Stadium.Number, the date which held the most games.

I am really not great at writing queries so this is all I have so far:

```
SELECT Number, count(Date)
FROM Stadium
ORDER BY Stadium.Number, Stadium.Date
```

Second Query - 
I need to list the Stadium.Number which have had at least 25% more games in them this January (2012-01), compared to last January (2011-01) Stadium.Date refers to the date of the games played.

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0):

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT Number, Date
FROM Stadium
group by Number,Date
order by count(Date) desc
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT Number,count(Date)
FROM Stadium
where date>='2012-01-01' and date <='2012-01-31'
group by Number
having count(Date)> ((select count(Date)
FROM Stadium
where date>='2011-01-01' and date <='2011-01-31')*0.25)
```

check this [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b1e2/7)

Comment: Same as above, I need the query to give Stadium.Number and the date which has the most games for that specific Stadium.Number

Comment: @user1745447 i change my answer ... check that

Comment: Problem with Query 1 - The query you have written is giving me the Stadium Number and the amount of games played there. I need it to give me the Stadium Number and the date which had the most games played for each Stadium Number.

Query 2 problem - I am getting SQL Error (1241): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: are you still there? So close on Query one now! Thanks.

Comment: @user1745447 Sorry... have u sort out ur problem?

Comment: @user1745447 i have modified answer for your query 1 answer. check demo

Answer (score 0):

I really think you should normalise your database schema, it would make queries like this very easy to solve.

For example - I think Stadium and Game should be 2 separate tables, with a 1 to many link.  (Or even many to many if a game can span over different stadiums).

But for your example:

```
SELECT s.Number AS Stadium, s.[Date], COUNT(s.[Date]) AS 'Count'
FROM Stadium s
GROUP BY s.Number, s.[Date]
ORDER BY s.Number, COUNT(s.[Date]) DESC
```

Assuming there is an Id on the Stadium table this will do for your second query - not sure if there is a more efficient way though.

```
SELECT s.Number AS Stadium,
       COUNT(y1.[Date]) AS Year1Count,
       COUNT(y2.[Date]) AS Year2Count,
       COUNT(y1.[Date]) / COUNT(y2.[Date]) * 100 AS Growth
FROM Stadium s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Stadium y1 ON s.Id = y1.Id AND y1.[Date] BETWEEN '2011-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2011-12-31 23:59:59'
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Stadium y2 ON s.Id = y2.Id AND y2.[Date] BETWEEN '2012-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-12-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY s.Number
HAVING COUNT(y1.[Date]) / COUNT(y2.[Date]) * 100 > 25
```

Comment: This query doesn't do what I need it to do; It needs to have in the results table for each Stadium.Number, the date that had the most games played.

Comment: Sorry - adjusted it - and added a 2nd query to achieve your second part.